# how to disable mouse when using touch screen monitor

Tags: vb.net

I want to disable the functionality of using a mouse when using a touch screen monitor in vb.net. The reason why I ask is because I want to limit users to only one option. is there a way I can code this in vb.net 2010.

Comment: A touch screen just emulates a mouse click so that won't limit what they can click either. Are you sure you don't want to just change the mouse icon to something that can't be seen?

Comment: A programmer cannot compete with a pair of scissors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a purely .NET way, but you can execute `devcon.exe` to find classes of devices (USB HID Mice for example) and disable them.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272

**Edit:** There is a [similar question that shows a .NET example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252390/362536).

See also:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HardwareHelper.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Just unplug the mouse.

If, for some reason, you can't do that, just disable it in Device Manager.

No code needed.

Comment: Surely there's a way to disable a device programmatically?

Comment: @Brad: Yes, but I'm guessing he doesn't need it.  Also, I don't know how to do that. :)

Comment: Ha, I'm sure you're correct, but this doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: just wanted to know, if i programmatically disable the mouse in the code, this wouldnt affect the way the touch screen monitor works right?

Comment: @Calvin: That depends how you do it.  If you disable the physical mouse device (a HID), the touch screen shouldn't be affected.

Comment: @SLaks: can you point me to the right direction on how i can code this in vb.net?